# send() commands in a loop just keep appending data

Tags: c, sockets

I have a TCP send() command inside of a loop. I am noticing that each message that I send just appends to the end of the previously sent message. I don't know why. I've tried both memset and bzero to clear my `char *`, but I get the same result. Anyone see why?

```
char *lsp = malloc(128);

for (i=0; i<3; i++) {

    memset (lsp, 0, 128); // also tried bzero here
    lsp_builder(lsp, this_router->label, routing_table, num_hosts-1, ++seq);
    fprintf (logfd, "\tCreated the following lsp: %s\n\n", lsp); //<--looks great

    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        send (sockfd[i], lsp, strlen(lsp), 0);
    }
}
```

Then, on the receiving end, I have this code:

```
char incoming_lsp[128];
bzero(incoming_lsp, sizeof(incoming_lsp));
recv(newfd[i], &incoming_lsp, sizeof(incoming_lsp), 0);

// this is where I can see the data being appended
fprintf(logfd, "\tReceived: %s\n", incoming_lsp);
```

Comment: There are no "messages" in TCP/IP. TCP/IP is **stream** oriented.

Comment: Also one should **always** check the value returend by `send()`/`write()` as at least for sockets they are not guaranteed to send/write out as much data as they were told to. Your code is not save to send out all you want it to send. Please see the relevant man pages closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send individual strings, you need to include their null terminators in the messages

```
send (sockfd[i], lsp, strlen(lsp)+1, 0);
//                               ^^
```

Note also that a single call to `recv` is not guaranteed to return a single, full buffer from `send`.  You need to check the return value from `recv` to see how many bytes it returns, calling it repeatedly in a loop until you read your target message length or find your target message terminator.

Comment: That solved it. I don't know if I ever would have seen that one. Thanks!